# Erro ao tentar inserir formulário no laravel com usuário autenticado (chave estrangeira para outra tabela)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou tentando inserir os dados de um formulário de uma classe Condomínio com o usuário já logado e autenticado , o user_id é chave estrangeira para a tabela Condomínio, no meu entendimento o método store já deveria trazer o user_id no array para inserir os dados mas isto não esta acontecendo, e por conta disso gera um erro SQL dizendo que o campo user_id não pode ser nulo(pois ele é uma chave estrangeira como disse).Segue os método create e store do CondomínioController:

```
public function create()
    {   
        $condominio = auth()->user()->condominio;
        //$condominio = Condominios::create()->get();
        $title='Cadastrar Condominio';
        return view('admin.condominio.create',compact('title')); 

    }


public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $condominio = auth()->user()->condominio;
    //dd($request->all());

    Condominios::create($request->all());


   return redirect()->route('admin.condominio.index')->with('message', 'condominio criado com sucesso!');
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se o campo `user_id` não estiver explicitamente definido na view ele não será preenchido, ou seja, ele não é injetado automagicamente.

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth()->user()->id }}">
```

** Não recomendo fazer dessa forma, visto que o campo pode ser editado.

Também pode ser feito assim:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $condominio = auth()->user()->condominio;

    $request['user_id'] = Auth()->user()->id;

    Condominios::create($request->all());


   return redirect()->route('admin.condominio.index')->with('message', 'condominio criado com sucesso!');
}
```

Na sua model é necessário declarar a propriedade `fillable` e informar quais campos podem ser preenchidos via [Mass Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel).

Exemplo:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'nome', 'teste'];
```

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: editei a resposta

Comment: David no array fillable não posso inserir user_id pois ele não é um campo de entrada para usuário , antes tinha conseguido fazendo desta forma mas é ganbiarra, tenho que conseguir passando pelo Auth mesmo , eu sei que é possível.

Comment: isso não é gambiarra, é a forma como o framework funciona. Se você quiser fazer de outro jeito vai ter que instanciar a model e setar os atributos 1 por 1 e no final da um $model->save()